# How do I concatenate strings but keep each individual null terminator?

Tags: c, string

```
void printHeader(char *Category_Names)
{
    printf("%s %s %s %s", Category_Names,(char*)Category_Names+15,(char*)Category_Names+30,(char*)Category_Names+45);
}
```

To begin, I have dumbed down this function for the sake of my question. For my class I am reading an input file that is essentially a grade book, and I am creating a linked list of students and their grades. Anyways, the top of the input file contains 4 categories separated by spaces. For example, "Quizzes Midterms Homework Final" is valid. We can assume for this project that each category is max 15 characters (or 14 if you don't count a null terminator). This is how I have read the input.

```
fscanf(file, "%15s %15s %15s %15[^\n]s%*c", category1, category2, category3, category4);
```

Now that I have gotten the background out of the way, I can finally ask my question. How can I concatenate these strings while keeping null terminators in the middle of the resulting string? Clearly it is crucial to have these null terminators based off the arguments in the printf call. Before anyone suggests I change around this method, I wish I could. This was provided by my professor, and I definitely would do it a different way if it was up to me. Thanks

Comment: why not use a proper array of strings?

Comment: If you read the line with `fgets` and then apply `sscanf` to the input string then you have both the separate and the combined strings. Aside: omit the `s` from `%15[^\n]s`, but if each line contains just four strings or values, you can discard all that line-end twiddling anyway, since the `scanf` function family filters whitespace.

Comment: Technically, you cannot.  By definition, a string is a null-terminated array of characters.  If you concatenate them into one string, you can have only one null-termiator.  But you probably do not actually want to concatenate them; you just want to occasionally write them as a single string.  Do that when you need to.

Comment: @OldProgrammer because OP says the professor says no.

Comment: What is your desired output? `Quizzes\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Midterms...` or `Quizzes\0Midterms...`?

Comment: I wonder why the casts in the `printHeader()` function — it's hard to see what type `CategoryName + 15` could have other than `char *`, so the casts are superfluous.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Quizzes\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Midterms...

Comment: You could try this: `char buf[60] = {0}; fscanf(file, "%14s %14s %14s %14s", buf, &buf[15], &buf[30], &buf[45]);`

Comment: Why not zero the entire 60-byte `Category_Names` array (or the array that will be passed to `printHeader()` as the argument), and then read the 4 strings into the appropriate offsets in the data.  Since the input is space-separated, the `%s` will be fine.  Note that `fscanf()` will happily read tabs and newlines as well as blanks between the words.  If it is all supposed to be on a single line, read the line (using `fgets()` or POSIX `geline()`) and then parse it with `sscanf()`.  Note that you should be using `%14s` in the `scanf()` calls; the size doesn't include the null byte.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I concatenate these strings while keeping null terminators in the middle of the resulting string?

Not possible to form a C *string* with anything after the *null character*.  The *string* ends at `'\0'`.

Instead, write 15*4 bytes using `fwrite()`

```
void printHeader(char *Category_Names) {
  //  printf("%s %s %s %s", Category_Names,(char*)Category_Names+15, ...
  fwrite(Category_Names, 15, 4, stdout);
}
```

Recommend to open the file in binary too.

---

Yet consider another approach if the 4 strings lack spaces, pad output with spaces. IMO, padding with *null character's* is not likely the approach to use.

```
printf("%14s %14s %14s %14s\n", 
  Category_Names, Category_Names+15,
  Category_Names+30, Category_Names+45);
```

Comment: `write(Category_Names, 15, 4, stdout);`? Typo?

Answer (score 0):

> Quizzes\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Midterms...

Usually, the semantics of `strncat` render it fairly confusing, but this is exactly what it was designed to do; possible [history](https://lwn.net/Articles/507376/). The are four `'\0'`'s that are actually not needed in this case except for convenience when extracting the strings, so one also has to set these. It is probably easier to do `struct { char s0[15], s1[15], s2[15], s3[15]; };`, but maybe your professor wouldn't like that.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <string.h> /* strncpy */

#define LEN 14

static char *str15cpy(char *const s1, const char *const s2) {
    char *const ret = strncpy(s1, s2, LEN);
    s1[LEN] = '\0';
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    char multistr[(LEN + 1) * 4];
    char *s0 = multistr, *s1 = multistr + LEN + 1,
        *s2 = multistr + (LEN + 1) * 2, *s3 = multistr + (LEN + 1) * 3;
    size_t i;
    str15cpy(s0, "quizzes");
    str15cpy(s1, "midterms");
    str15cpy(s2, "homework");
    str15cpy(s3, "final");
    /* This is what it looks like in memory. */
    for(i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        { const char a = multistr[i]; printf("%c", a ? a : '0'); }
    fputc('\n', stdout);
    /* Since the strings are '\0' terminated (convenient) already, you can, */
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", s0, s1, s2, s3);
    return 0;
}
```

And use binary I/O with fixed length records.